# How to use Alerts instead of Notifications using Android Estimote Beacon

Tags: java, android, alert, estimote, beacon

I am fairly new to Android development and just recently started trying out the Estimote Beacon development kit and was following the initial tutorials on: [Android Tutorial Background Monitoring](http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-2-background-monitoring/)

I followed this tutorial and created an app that popped up a notification when the phone was in the proximity of the beacon. My app has a MainActivity class as well as the following MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private BeaconManager beaconManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());


    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
                beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region(
                        "monitored region",
                        UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"),
                        5461, 23416));

        }
    });

    beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
            showNotification(
                    "Your gate closes in 47 minutes.",
                    "Current security wait time is 15 minutes, "
                            + "and it's a 5 minute walk from security to the gate. "
                            + "Looks like you've got plenty of time!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
            // could add an "exit" notification too if you want (-:
        }
    });
}

public void showNotification(String title, String message) {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0,
            new Intent[] { notifyIntent }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

However I would like my application to display an Alert instead of a Notification and I've been informed that you cannot set alerts into the MyApplication class as it is not an Activity and therefore does not have a theme.

Is there a way I can set the AlertDialog from the MainActivity class when an OnEnteredRegion is triggered inside the MyApplication class?

Thanks